# Why Inet6Address.getByAddress requires both hostname AND direct address bytes?

Tags: java, networking

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html

```
public static Inet6Address getByAddress(String host,
                        byte[] addr,
                        int scope_id)
```

`Inet6Address` is supposed to hold something like `sockaddr_in6` sans port number (16 address bytes plus scope_id if link-local), at least what I think of it. Given 16 bytes and scope id, I suppose that `Inet6Address` should be fully specified, without the need for further bits. Yet there is extra argument `host`...

Documentation links to explanation of `InetAddr.getByAddress(String,byte[])`, which also contains unclear snippet:

> Creates an InetAddress based on the provided host name and IP address. No name service is checked for the validity of the address.
> The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or a textual representation of its IP address.
>
> No validity checking is done on the host name either.

If no DNS then why hostname is needed at all when there are already bytes supplied? Will it work with `null` instead of host? Why there is no `getByAddress` with just `addr` and `scope_id` (without `host`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there is a factory method that takes just the byte array and does what you'd expect:

```
byte[] addr = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
InetAddress ip = Inet6Address.getByAddress(addr);
```

However, we're interested in the hostname part, so let's read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName--) for `getHostName()`:

> Gets the host name for this IP address.
>
> If this InetAddress was created with a host name, this host name will
>   be remembered and returned;otherwise, a reverse name lookup will be
>   performed and the result will be returned based on the system configured
>   name lookup service.

We've built that first IP address without a hostname, so according to the javadoc, calling `getHostName()` will perform an actual lookup. This may or many not be what we want so java gives us a second option. If we build the address like this:

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByAddress("foo", addr);
```

Then `getHostName()` would simply print the hostname which *we* gave (`foo`) without any lookup.

Btw, the same explanation can be found in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) for `InetAddress` itself:

> An instance of an InetAddress consists of an IP address **and possibly
>   its corresponding host name (depending on whether it is constructed
>   with a host name or whether it has already done reverse host name
>   resolution).**

Comment: "there is a factory method that takes just the byte array and does what you'd expect" -> Is there corresponding method that takes byte array and scope id?

Comment: @Vi. Kinda. You'd get the same effect by passing a hostname of `null`. It's not great since the this behavior isn't documented anywhere, so it might change between Java versions or maybe even JDK implementations. Still, that's the only equivalent API I'm aware of. I completely agree that it's a weird choice for an API.